# How can I solve the progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Sum of first three member of arithmetic progression equal $21$. If from one and two first members deduct $1$ and third member add $2$, it will be a geometric progression.

first member
$$a_1 - 1$$
second member
$$a_1 + d - 1$$
third member
$$a_1 + 2d + 2$$

$$S_3 = \frac{a_1 - 1 + a_1 + d - 1 + a_1 + 2d + 2}{2} \cdot 3 = 21$$
$$S_3 = \frac{2a_1 + 2d}{2} \cdot 3 = 21$$
$$S_3 = a_1 + d = 7$$
$$a_1 = 7 - d$$
$$(a_1 + d - 1)^2 = (a1 + 2d + 2)(a_1 - 1)$$
In book says next solving will be such.
$$d^2 + 3d - 18 = 0$$
But if I solve it I get that $$(6 - d)^2 = (9 + d)(6 - d)$$ and 
$$(6 - d)^2 = 54 - 3d - d^2$$
Can you explain me my error and show right solving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine up to $$(a_1 + d - 1)^2 = (a_1 + 2d + 2)(a_1 - 1)$$ included. Now replace $a_1$ by $7-d$ as you proved it. So $$(7-d+d-1)^2=(7-d+2d+2)(7-d-1)$$ $$36=(9+d)(6-d)$$ Expand $$36=54-3d-d^2$$ which, after simplification, is the answer from the book. Now, solve the quadratic to get $d$, then $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $a-d$, $a$, $a+d$ as three terms of AP.

Sum=$3a=21\implies a=7$

Terms of AP:
$7-d$, $7$, $7+d$

Terms of GP:
$6-d$, $6$, $9+d$

$36=(6-d)(9+d)$

$d^2+3d-18=0$

$d=3,-6$

Hence, Terms of AP:
$4, 7, 10$ or $13, 7, 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Question is slightly unclear: if you are wondering how $(a_1+d−1)^2=(a_1+2d+2)(a_1−1)$ became $d^2+3d−18=0$, expand and apply $a_1=(7-d)$

Solve $d^2+3d−18=0$ like a simple quadratic equation!

Answer (score 1):

i have got the following System:
$$a_1+d-1=q(a_1-1)$$
$$a_1+2d+2=q^2(a_1-1)$$
$$a_1+d=7$$
solving this we get
$$a_1=13,d=-6,q=1/2$$
$$a_1=4,d=3,q=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the first 3 members be x,y and z, such that

$x+y+z=21$

Also,

$y=x+d$,

$z=x+2d$

$\implies x+d=7=y$

So, Second term is 7.

It also says,

$x-1,y-1,z+2$ form a geometric progression.

Then,

$\frac{y-1}{x-1}=\frac{z+2}{y-1}$

${(y-1)^2}=(x-1)(z+2)$

$36=(x-1)(z+2)$

Now, $x=7-d$ How? Because you are at the second term, deducing the common difference shall give us the first term (logically), and adding common difference shall give us the third term!

So,

$(7-d-1)(7+d+2)=36$

$(6-d)(9+d)=36$

$54+6d-9d-d^2=36$

$18-3d-d^2=0$

$d^2+3d-18=0$

$d^2+6d-3d-18=0$

$d(d+6)-3(d+6)=0$

$\implies d=-6$ and$d=3$

So,
Your series could be(original)

$13,7,1$ or $4,7,10$

Geometric series would be :

$12,6,3$

$r=\frac{1}{2}$

Or,

$3,6,12$

$r=2$